# Open mobile GPS enable setting page in onsen UI

Tags: android, gps, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

We are building hybrid application on onsen ui and using location service.  Like in iOS Native app If Location service is disabled, the onsen app should show popup that will **redirect to setting->privacy page**. So that user can enable location service.

i am able to detect that GPS is enable or not but i am unable to redirect to GPS enable page.someone please help me to redirect setting page in Android and IOS both.

**code is Below**

```
if (navigator.geolocation)
    {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(

            function( position )
            {
                init(position);
                if (Location_Marker)
                {
                    return;
                }
                Location_Marker = Add_Marker(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,"Initial Position");
            },

            function( error ){
                switch(error.code)
                {
                    **case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:**
                            console.log( "Permission Denied: ", error );
                            ons.notification.alert({message:'Please Enable GPS'});
                            break;
                    **case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:**
                            console.log( "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: ", error );
                            ons.notification.confirm({message:'GPS signals are weak'});

                            break;
                }
                console.log( "Something went wrong: ", error );
                GeoLocation_Not_Supported();
            }, 

        );

    }
```

**if Permission Denied i want to open mobile setting page so that user can enable GPS**

Comment: Post your code so that we could help

Comment: function( error ){
     switch(error.code)
     {
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        console.log( "Permission Denied: ", error );
                                ons.notification.alert({message:'Please Enable GPS'});
                                break;
      case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        console.log( "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: ", error );
                                ons.notification.confirm({message:'GPS signals are weak'});
                               
        break;
     }
     
     GeoLocation_Not_Supported();
    },

Comment: if PERMISSION_DENIED then i want to open setting page of mobile to enable GPS

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can use this way:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivityForResult(callGPSSettingIntent, 100);
```

Comment: Could you please help me by using code in javascript or angular js.

Answer (score 0):

I use  the following snippet to do so.

```
LocationManager manager;
private final int  REQUEST_CODE = 2;

manager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

if (!manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And in `onActivityResult` I will do my work if the user has enabled GPS or not

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
           // do your awesome stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please help me by using code in javascript or angular js.